# C# - loading inherited class

Tags: c#

I have a class called `FieldDesc`.

```
public class FieldDesc {
    public FieldDesc() {
    }
}
```

I also have another class that inherits from `FieldDesc` called `StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType`.

```
public class StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType: FieldDesc {
    public StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType() {
    }
}
```

In my control I have -

```
FieldDesc aTable;
aTable = new FieldDesc();

String TableName = "StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType";
```

What do I have to do to get `aTable` to know that it is an object of type `StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType` ?

Comment: It isn't an object of `StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType`.  You declared it as a `new FieldDesc()`

Comment: you have to assign `aTable = new StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType()`. Otherwise it's not possible to cast it into StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType

Comment: In your code example, `aTable` will always be of type `FieldDesc` because it is constructed as such. What goal are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Bernard - I am trying to have a base class that encompasses the functionality I need where the child classes are specific to specific tables. That way when I instantiate a FieldDesc, I don't want to have to tell it to load the child class, but to load the base classe's definitions that were defined via the child class. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the two classes

```
public class FieldDesc
{
    public FieldDesc()
    {
    }

    public void A()
    {
    }

    public virtual void V()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("V from FieldDesc");
    }
}

public class StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType : FieldDesc
{
    public StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType()
    {
    }

    public void B()
    {
    }

    public overrides void V()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("V from StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType");
    }
}
```

You can do this

```
FieldDesc fd = new StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType();
StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType svc = new StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType();

fd.A(); // OK
fd.B(); // Fails (does not compile)
((StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType)fd).B(); // OK
fd.V(); // OK, prints "V from StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType"

svc.A(); // OK
svc.B(); // OK
svc.V(); // OK, prints "V from StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType"
```

The derived class is assignment compatible to the base class; however, accessed through a variable typed as the base class you will only see the the members of the base class.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. Are you trying to declare aTable as a StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType or trying to determine if it has been declared as one?

If you're trying to declare:

```
FieldDesc aTable;
aTable = new StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType();
```

That'll work as long as StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType inherits from FieldDesc

If you're trying to determine type:

```
if(aTable is StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use is operator to find this out

```
if(someObject is StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType )
    {
       //it means is is object of StandardHoursByCommunitySvcType  type
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate all of the input, but if I want to declare an object specific to the child class, I canjust instantiate that child class. I am trying to abstract that specification away from the control. Is there a way to use TableName that specifies which child class to use?